# Verilog multiple drivers

Tags: verilog, xilinx, system-verilog, bcd

I'm trying to make BCD Counter using Verilog that will be connected to 7-segment decoder.
After I synthesize it, the error occured like this: 
**`Multi-source in Unit <BCDcountmod> on signal <BCD0<3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.>`**And more.....

***Any solution?*** (*Here's my code below*)

```
module BCDcountmod(
  input Clock, Clear, up, down,
  output [3:0] BCD1_1, BCD0_0 );
reg [3:0] BCD1, BCD0;
//reg [3:0] BCD1_1, BCD0_0;
always @(posedge Clock) begin
  if (Clear) begin
    BCD1 <= 0;
    BCD0 <= 0;
    end
end


 always @(posedge up) begin
      if (BCD0 == 4'b1001) begin
        BCD0 <= 0;
        if (BCD1 == 4'b1001)
          BCD1 <= 0;
        else
          BCD1 <= BCD1 + 1;
      end
      else
        BCD0 <= BCD0 + 1;
    end


always @(posedge down) begin
      if (BCD0 == 4'b0000) begin
        BCD0 <= 4'b1001;
        if (BCD1 == 4'b1001)
          BCD1 <= 4'b1001;
        else
          BCD1 <= BCD1 - 1;
      end
      else
        BCD0 <= BCD0 - 1;
    end

 assign BCD1_1 = BCD1;
 assign BCD0_0 = BCD0;

endmodule
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93932/connected-to-multiple-drivers-problem-verilog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to mcleod_ideafix's answer you have this block:

```
always @(posedge Clock) begin
  if (Clear) begin
    BCD1 <= 0;
    BCD0 <= 0;
    end
end
```

Which implies a synchronous clear, I am not sure if that is your intention as typically you would have an asynchronous clear for you flip-flops in ASIC design, or set initial state for FPGA.

For a flip-flop with an asynchronous active-high clear

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge clear) begin
  if (clear) begin
    BCD1 <= 'b0;  //NB: defined widths
    BCD0 <= 'b0;
  end
  else
    // normal logic
  end
end
```

It is more typical to use active-low resets:

```
always @(posedge clock or negedge clear_n) begin
  if (~clear_n) begin
    BCD1 <= 'b0;  //NB: defined widths
    BCD0 <= 'b0;
  end
  else
    if (up == 1'b1) begin
      // up logic
    end
    else if (down == 1'b1) begin
      // down logic
    end
    else begin 
      // nothing to see here
    end
  end
end
```

Doing comparisons with `== 1'b1` means you will get a width mismatch warning instead of weird behaviour if the LHS (left hand side) is wider than 1 bit.

I also noticed that you have:

```
output [3:0] BCD1_1, BCD0_0 );
reg [3:0] BCD1, BCD0;
assign BCD1_1 = BCD1;
assign BCD0_0 = BCD0;
```

You just needed to do the following to have reg's as outputs:

```
output reg [3:0] BCD1, BCD0
```

Although I find the following much clearer:

```
output reg [3:0] BCD1,
output reg [3:0] BCD0
```

Comment: There is also a bug in the SO's BCD1 down counter. `if (BCD1 == 4'b1001) BCD1 <= 4'b1001;` should be `if (BCD1 == 4'b0000) BCD1 <= 4'b1001;`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify `BCD` from different `always` blocks. Any modification should be perfomed in only one `always`. Something like:

```
module BCDcountmod(
  input Clock, Clear, up, down,
  output [3:0] BCD1_1, BCD0_0 );
  reg [3:0] BCD1, BCD0;
//reg [3:0] BCD1_1, BCD0_0;

  assign BCD1_1 = BCD1;
  assign BCD0_0 = BCD0;  

  always @(posedge Clock) begin
    //---- IS IT CLEAR? --------------
    if (Clear) begin
      BCD1 <= 0;
      BCD0 <= 0;
    end
    //---- IS IT UP? --------------
    else if (up) then begin
      if (BCD0 == 4'b1001) begin
        BCD0 <= 0;
        if (BCD1 == 4'b1001)
          BCD1 <= 0;
        else
          BCD1 <= BCD1 + 1;
      end
    end
    //---- IS IT DOWN? --------------
    else if (down) begin
      if (BCD0 == 4'b0000) begin
        BCD0 <= 4'b1001;
        if (BCD1 == 4'b1001)
          BCD1 <= 4'b1001;
        else
          BCD1 <= BCD1 - 1;
      end
      else
        BCD0 <= BCD0 - 1;
    end
  end
endmodule
```