# Verilog code motion estimator

Tags: debugging, verilog, system-verilog

I having trouble with finding the smallest values of X and xfind and Y and yfind in `Costcalculator xfind (X,xcost);
Costcalculator yfind (Y,ycost);

in code below. 
can someone comment please. For some reason I couldn't import the whole code. It just recognizes these lines as codes. Sorry if it is not clear.

```
  always @(posedge clk)   // sequential circuit

  begin

    Costcalculator xfind (X,xcost);
    Costcalculator yfind (Y,ycost); 

    if(reset)
      begin 
        i=0;
        R<=0;
        xcost<=0;
        ycost<=0;
        mode0<=0;
        mode1<=0;
        mode2<=0;
        mode3<=0;
        mode4<=0;
        mode5<=0;
        mode6<=0;
      end   //if end
        else
      begin
            for (i=1; i<43;  i=i+1)
      begin
               R<=xcost+ycost;
         costholder <= SAD+(lambda*R);   // Here we calculate the cost of a sub-blocks As the clock
                if (i<17)
         mode0<=costholder+mode0;
       else if(i>16 && i<25)
         mode1<=costholder+mode1;
       else if(i>24 && i<33) 
         mode2<=costholder+mode2;
       else if(i==33 || i==34 || i==35 || i==36 )
         mode3<=costholder+mode3;
       else if(i==37 || i==38)
         mode4<=costholder+mode4;
       else if(i==39 || i==40)
         mode5<=costholder+mode5;
       else if(i==41)
         mode6<=costholder+mode6;

       end    //for end
    end   //else end
  end   //always end
```

Module `Costcalculator`:

```
//**********************************************************‌​** 
module Costcalculator (motionvector, cost); // X AND Y COST CALCULATOR 
input [4:0]motionvector; 
output [2:0]cost; 
reg [2:0]cos; 
wire [3:0] vector; 
assign vector = {motionvector[3:0] }; 

always @* begin 
case (vector) 0 : cos=0; 
1,2 : cos=1; 
3,4,5,6 : cos=2; 
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 : cos=3; 
15 : cos=4; 
endcase 
end 
assign cost = cos; 
endmodule 
//**********************************************************‌​**
```

Comment: What is the error? I believe `Constcalculator` is a module. You can not instantiate a module in a procedural block.

Comment: You should try to 1) make a minimal (not) working design, 2) make sure we have all relevant code and 3) provide a clue about what's wrong. So you should remove all irrelevant code, tell us what is "Costcalculator", probably a module as pointed out by sharvil111 considering the syntax you used and 3) give us the error code/tell us what is wrong? Impossible to answer otherwise ...

Comment: Here is rest of the code:

Comment: //************************************************************
module Costcalculator (motionvector, cost);   // X AND Y COST CALCULATOR
  input [4:0]motionvector;
  output [2:0]cost;
  reg [2:0]cos;
  wire [3:0] vector;
  assign vector = {motionvector[3:0] };  

  always @*
  begin
  case (vector)
    0                    : cos=0;
    1,2                  : cos=1;
    3,4,5,6              : cos=2;
    7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 : cos=3;
    15                   : cos=4;
  endcase
  end
  assign cost = cos;
endmodule
//************************************************************

Comment: It gives the syntax error: Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "design.sv", 97: token is '('
      Costcalculator xfind (X,xcost);
                            ^

Comment: yes, you are right, I took the costcalculator out of always  @(posedge clk) and it gives this error:  Illegal combination of structural and procedural drivers.
  Variable "ycost" is driven by an invalid combination of structural and 
  procedural drivers. Variables driven by a structural driver cannot have any other drivers. for xcost too   This variable is declared at "design.sv", 87: reg ycost;
  The first driver is at "design.sv", 93: Costcalculator yfind(Y, ycost);
  The second driver is at "design.sv", 105: ycost <= 0;

Comment: So in short, it says xcost is derived twice, one in Costcalculator xfind (X,xcost); and another time in     if(reset)
      begin 
        i=0;
        R<=0;
        xcost<=0;
        ycost<=0;

Answer (score 1):

After taking the module outside the `always` block, you are driving `xconst` and `yconst` from two places. On the other hand, I don't see drivers of `X` and `Y`.

Since `Costcalculator` is a purely combinational module, you need to just provide the **inputs** `X` and `Y` as zero from the top/wrapper module.

```
//.. some stuff
if(reset) begin
//... some other signals
X <= 0;
Y <=0;
//...
```

As the error says about **multiple drivers**, you are driving `xconst` and `yconst` form two modules. On reset, if you provide `X` and `Y` as `0` from the wrapping module, then automatically the `vector` will go to Zero and ultimately the `cost` which is the output of module will become Zero. Thereby the variables `xconst` and `yconst` will become zero.

Refer to [this similar forum question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630572/verilog-multiple-drivers) for more information.